# using Helpers.callAction with controllers without static methods in Play framework 2.1.4

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm using play framework 2.1.4 with Guice to inject dependencies to my controllers.

In my tests, I would like to call `Helpers.callAction`. Though `controllers.routes.ref.Mycontroller` doesn't know about my action since they are not static.

Is there a way to get the `HandlerRef` somehow to pass it to `callAction` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We end up using Jukito https://code.google.com/p/jukito/

It needs to be cleaned (we can create our own helpers for that) but here's the basic idea

```
@RunWith(JukitoRunner.class)
public class AuthenticationTest {
    @Inject
    private Authentication authentication;

    private String username = "username";
    private String password = "password";

    @Before
    public void setupMocks(UserDao mockedUserDao) throws RecordNotFoundException {
        ObjectNode json = Json.newObject();
        json.put("username", username);
        json.put("password", password);

        User mockedUser = mock(User.class);
        when(mockedUser.getEmail()).thenReturn("email@test.com");

        Http.RequestBody mockedBody = mock(Http.RequestBody.class);
        when(mockedBody.asJson()).thenReturn(json);

        Http.Request mockedRequest = mock(Http.Request.class);
        when(mockedRequest.body()).thenReturn(mockedBody);

        when(mockedUserDao.findByEmailAndPassword(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(mockedUser);

        Http.Context.current.set(new Http.Context((long) 1, mock(play.api.mvc.RequestHeader.class),
                mockedRequest, new HashMap<String, String>(), new HashMap<String, String>(),
                new HashMap<String, Object>()));
    }

    @Test
    public void loginTest(UserDao mockedUserDao) throws RecordNotFoundException {
        //Arrange
        FakeApplication app = Helpers.fakeApplication();
        start(app);

        ObjectNode json = Json.newObject();
        json.put("username", username);
        json.put("password", password);

        //act
        authentication.login();
        stop(app);

        //Assert
        verify(mockedUserDao).findByEmailAndPassword(anyString(), anyString());
        assertEquals(200, status(result));
    }
}
```

Comment: using the scala version would so much easier... https://github.com/typesafehub/play-guice/blob/master/test/controllers/ApplicationTest.scala